# TCPDF Include Calibri

Tags: php, tcpdf

I 'm trying to add Calibri to TCPDF, and I 've used:

```
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('calibri.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 12);
```

However, this works only with the plain font, all bold/italic elements in my text are not shown with these attributes. However I have also calibrib.ttf in the same folder.

How should I tell TCPDF to use the bold version, like it does for the default embedded fonts?

Comment: I have the same problem, So that i use calibri.ttf where i need plain font and calibrib.ttf for bold font. which works but not a perfect solution.

Comment: I fixed in a weird way. I just added the ttfs in the same dir and did nothing related to TCPDF functions. Then it worked.

Comment: Can you please show some code example.

Comment: $pdf->SetFont("Calibri", '', 12);
just before any addPage. The current directory contains the ttf files.